# MonoTouch UITableViewController with xib

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitableview

In MonoTouch, I have a utility class called say "MyTableViewController" that derives from UITableViewController and implements a bunch of useful tableview controllery related stuff.  It works fine if I'm instantiating it in code, but I'd now like to make a tableview controller that's loaded from a xib - eg: it has a toolbar at the bottom.

In ObjectiveC, I'd simply hook up the tableview instance in the Xib with the UITableViewController's `tableView` property.

In MonoTouch however this property isn't marked as an outlet and doesn't appear in XCode's interface builder so I can't hook it up, resulting in an exception from ObjectiveC about the nib being loaded but "but didn't get a UITableView".

Is there some way I can declare an outlet on my derived controller class that can be bound to from the xib?  Other options or workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out... the tableView property doesn't need to be hooked up in the xib.  Rather the tableView in the xib should be connected to the File Owners view (ie: the controller).